# Missing keyword - inner join with where

Tags: oracle

post_code is a primary key in the location table and foreign key in job. I am trying to join them, could anyone help.

```
SELECT job.start_date, job.cust_id, job.veh_id, location.post_code, location.country_name_location
FROM job
INNER JOIN location job.post_code ON location.post_code AND country_name_location = 'France';




SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ON` is in the wrong position:

```
SELECT job.start_date, job.cust_id, job.veh_id, location.post_code, location.country_name_location
FROM job
INNER JOIN location ON job.post_code = location.post_code AND country_name_location = 'France';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your syntax. The `ON` keyword is meant to come after you specify the table you are joining with. So the correct query would be:

```
SELECT job.start_date, job.cust_id, job.veh_id, location.post_code, location.country_name_location
FROM job
INNER JOIN location ON job.post_code = location.post_code AND country_name_location = 'France';
```